# Laravel only join linked model if parent has boolean switch

Tags: php, laravel, query-builder

I'm using Laravel 8 and have two models: `Domain` and `Certificate`. A domain can have one certificate.

On my domain model, I have a boolean column called `certificate_checks_enabled`, and where I'm querying my domain, I'd like to include the certificate model on the domain only if the `certificate_checks_enabled` for that particular domain is true.

My end result might mean that I have 10 domains, and only 5 of them have the checks enabled, so only 5 of my 10 returned domain entries should include the `Certificate` model, what am I missing in my current query to achieve this:

```php
$domains = Domain::where('user_id', Auth::id())
            ->where(function ($sql) use ($search) {
              $sql->orWhere('domain', 'like', "$search%")
                  ->orWhere('status', 'like', "$search%")
                  ->orWhere('registrar', 'like', "$search%");
            })
            ->whereHas('certificate', function($query) {
                $query->where('certificate.certificate_checks_enabled', true)->get();
            })
            ->orderBy($sort[0] ?? 'expires_on', $sort[1] ?? 'desc')
            ->paginate((int) $perPage);
```

Comment: You're not missing anything, you just have an extra `->get()` inside your `whereHas()`. Also, is your table called `certificate` or `certificates`? When you do `where('certificate.certificate_checks_enabled')`, `certificate` is the table name (which is generally pluralized to `certificates`), not the relationship name (which is properly singularized as `certificate` for a `one-one` relationship).

Answer (score 1):

if you want only domains that have certificates you should use `WHEREHAS` (**5 out of 10 , only certificated**):

change :

```
whereHas('certificate', function($query) {
                $query->where('certificate.certificate_checks_enabled', true)->get();
            })
```

to this:

```
whereHas('certificate', function($query) {
                return $query->where('certificate.certificate_checks_enabled', true);
            })
```

But if you want **all domains**, and if they had certificates, join them to main query (**10 out of 10, all, with certified joint**):

change :

```
whereHas('certificate', function($query) {
                $query->where('certificate.certificate_checks_enabled', true)->get();
            })
```

to this:

```
with(['certificate' => function($query) {
                $query->where('certificate.certificate_checks_enabled', true);
            }])
```

Read more at https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading